# Automatically run as administrator programs on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to run some program with other domain users. For example;

Program: X
My domain : Y
Other domain user: Z

I tried " runas /u:Y\Z X " but always I have to enter other domain user password. I want to enter password only one time then program should run same user and password without ask password.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file or similar in a start-up folder with the contents:

```
runas /user:domain\admin C:\Path\To\ProcessExplorer.exe
```

Before rebooting, run

```
runas /savecred /user:domain\admin C:\Path\To\ProcessExplorer.exe
```

It will prompt you for the password only this one time; note that the admin password will be saved to your Windows profile (not usually a good idea); and this does not work for Win7 Home or Starter editions.